# How much is my position worth after 5-1 stock split?

Tags: stocks, stock-split

How much should my position be after a 5-1 stock split. For ever 5 shares, I get 1 share.

My position before split:

```
500 shares of ABC with average price of $25.

ABC is trading at $9.  My position is worth $8000 ($12500 - $4500).
```

After the 5-1 split:

```
100 shares of ABC with avg price of ??

ABC is trading at $45.
```

What should my average price be?

I think it comes out to 100 @ $125?

Comment: Your position is worth $4500 before the split as well as after the split.

Comment: Is this a 5:1 split or 1:5 reverse split?  The 500 @ 9 to 100 @ 45 makes it look like a reverse split; your position would be $4500 in both cases.   Most stock trackers do not differentiate between these types, they're both split events.

Comment: @NorgateData What are you talking about? This is absolutely a reverse split - It's a 1:5 split not a 5:1 split. OP gets 1 share _for_ every 5 they owned, hence a 1 _for_ 5 or 1:5 reverse split. After a reverse split, you always end up with _fewer_ shares than you started with, but they're worth _more_. After a regular split, you end up with _more_ shares that are worth _less_. Because each share _split_ into multiple shares.

Comment: Comment withdrawn - I must have misunderstood the OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average price would be $125 which would be used to compute your basis. You paid $12,500 for the stock that is now worth $4,500 which is a loss of $8,000 overall if you sell at this point.